# Removing "Recently Viewed" From search

Tags: magento-1.9

We use an external search system for the search on our website, but when we search the default magento "You've recently viewed" loads and then the search results show. How can we disable the "you've Recently viewed" block from our search page?

I have tried looking in the `2columns-right` template which is located within the page folder which is in `app -> design -> Theme -> Default -> template ->page`  and there is nothing there about the recently viewed products.

Is there a way which we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much effort needed.

Just change `2columns-right.phtml` into `1column.phtml` in layout.xml

This will remove entire right section & display the search result in one column.

**OR**

if you want to remove only Recently viewed then

```
app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\reports\product_viewed.phtml
```

This section comes from above file.

Comment: Will the second option remove Recently viewed only in search?

Comment: No other places like (ex. category page) also use the same file. So there also it will be removed.

Comment: If you want to remove only for search page then just remove it from the search layout from XML.